# Unhandled exception error with two dimensional array

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

This dynamic programming algorithm is returning unhandled exception error probably due to the two dimensional arrays that I am using for various (and very large) number of inputs. I can't seem to figure out the issue here. The complete program as follows:

```
// A Dynamic Programming based solution for 0-1 Knapsack problem
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10000


int size;
int Weight;
int p[MAX];
int w[MAX];

// A utility function that returns maximum of two integers
int maximum(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }

// Returns the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
int i, w;
int retVal;
int **K;
K = (int**)calloc(n+1, sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < n + 1; ++i)
{
    K[i] = (int*)calloc(W + 1, sizeof(int));
}

// Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
        {
    if (i == 0 || w == 0)
      K[i][w] = 0;

            else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
      K[i][w] = maximum(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);

            else
          K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
    }
}

retVal = K[n][W];
for (i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    free(K[i]);
free(K);
return retVal;
}

int random_in_range(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
int base_random = rand();
if (RAND_MAX == base_random) return random_in_range(min, max);

int range = max - min,
    remainder = RAND_MAX % range,
    bucket = RAND_MAX / range;

if (base_random < RAND_MAX - remainder) {
    return min + base_random / bucket;
}
else {
    return random_in_range(min, max);
}
}

int main()
{
srand(time(NULL));
int val = 0;
int i, j;
//each input set is contained in an array
int batch[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 5000, 10000 };
int sizeOfBatch = sizeof(batch) / sizeof(batch[0]);
//algorithms are called per size of the input array
for (i = 0; i < sizeOfBatch; i++){

    printf("\n");
    //dynamic array allocation (variable length to avoid stack overflow
    //calloc is used to avoid garbage values
    int *p = (int*)calloc(batch[i], sizeof(int));
    int *w = (int*)calloc(batch[i], sizeof(int));
    for (j = 0; j < batch[i]; j++){
        p[j] = random_in_range(1, 500);
        w[j] = random_in_range(1, 100);
    }
    size = batch[i];
    Weight = batch[i] * 25;

    printf("|   %d ", batch[i]);
    printf("   %d", knapSack(Weight, w, p, size));

    free(p);
    free(w);

}

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Except for returning a value from `K` after freeing it (which will most likely cause some sort of damage), this seems to be the only indexing operation that can cause a problem: `K[i - 1][j - w[i - 1]]`, which might occur if `w[i - 1]` is negative.

Comment: The ranging is correct. If the inputs are small (say less than 100) then the program runs fine. But when the input size goes up to 5000 or more these message appears:

Comment: If you still have trouble after fixing the barak's suggestion then post a complete program that shows the problem

Comment: Also, check `calloc` did not return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```
for (i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    free(K[i]);
free(K);
return K[size][Weight];
```

**To this:**

```
int retVal;
...
retVal = K[size][Weight];
for (i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
    free(K[i]);
free(K);
return retVal;
```

Comment: Problem exists. The error message keeps coming up as such:Unhandled exception at 0x009A1505 in knapsack3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: The solution must be something very simple, but I can't seem to find it.